# Blur a specific part of an image

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, image-processing, scipy

I have an image. Like this:

[image]

I detect a subject(which is a person in this case) & it masks the image like this:

[image]

I want the background of the subject to be blurrred. Like this:

[image]

Below is the code I have tried. the following code only blurs

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os


path = 'selfies\\'
selfImgs = os.listdir(path)


for image in selfImgs:

    img = cv2.imread(path+image)
    img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    blur = cv2.blur(img,(10,10))
    #canny = cv2.Canny(blur, 10, 30)

    #plt.imshow(canny)
    plt.imshow(blur)

    j=cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    print(image)
    cv2.imwrite('blurred\\'+image+".jpg",j)
```

Is there any way by which I can blur only specific part/parts of the image.

This project is based on https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN

I can provide more information if required.

I have an approach in numpy :-

```
final_image = original * mask + blurred * (1-mask)
```

Comment: What you would do is blur the entire image and then combine the original and the blurred one according to the mask (e.g. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469235/opencv-apply-mask-to-a-color-image)).

Answer (score 21):

You may use `np.where()` method to select the pixels where you want blurred values and then replace them as:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("/home/user/Downloads/lena.png")
blurred_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (21, 21), 0)

mask = np.zeros((512, 512, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
# For older OpenCV <= 3
# mask = cv2.circle(mask, (258, 258), 100, np.array([255, 255, 255]), -1)
# out = np.where(mask==np.array([255, 255, 255]), img, blurred_img)

# For latest OpenCV
mask = cv2.circle(mask, (258, 258), 100, (255, 255, 255), -1)
out = np.where(mask==(255, 255, 255), img, blurred_img)

cv2.imwrite("./out.png", out)
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly. Using masks is the most common and efficient way.

Comment: @ZdaR I get TypeError: Scalar value for argument 'color' is not numeric

Comment: At which line of code, maybe you have some different version of OpenCV installed and the code may require minor tweaks. Can you share the full traceback?

Comment: @ZdaR, in my case I needed to replace `np.array([255, 255, 255])` with `(255, 255, 255)` globally. using opencv-python==4.1.0.25.

Answer (score 6):

As `ZdaR` said:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("/home/user/Downloads/lena.png")
blurred_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (21, 21), 0)

mask = np.zeros((512, 512, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
mask = cv2.circle(mask, (258, 258), 100, np.array([255, 255, 255]), -1)

out = np.where(mask==np.array([255, 255, 255]), img, blurred_img)

cv2.imwrite("./out.png", out)
```

This is good idea but I've got same error as `penta`:

> @ZdaR I get TypeError: Scalar value for argument 'color' is not numeric

A simple solution is to modify color value when you create Circle:

```
mask = cv2.circle(mask, (258, 258), 100, (255, 255,255), -1)
```

just CHANGE `np.array([255,255,255])`  to  `(255,255,255)`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what tools you use for subject detection, but if you have a way to copy the subject, you can first copy the whole image and then blur it. finally, you can copy the subject on the blurred image.
if it gives false and true on pixels in oppose to giving borders, you can just bitwise it.