# Tracking and bluring faces in multiple 360 images via python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

Is there a way to track down and nicely blur faces or part of face (like hair) for multiple 360 degree images via python opencv. ? I'am using Windows OS and python3.8

Answer (score 1):

Two methods with opencv and python

1. Using a Gaussian blur to anonymize faces in images and video streams
2. Applying a “pixelated blur” effect to anonymize faces in images and video

The method is well explained [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/04/06/blur-and-anonymize-faces-with-opencv-and-python/) and you can access code.

Now, a more advance solution if you are using GPU, and you want to run the application on a live video stream.. its with nvidia DS and Deep Learning. The github here reports results on T4, i believe you should be able to run it on Jetson nano. Here is the [link](https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/redaction_with_deepstream)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. First you need to detect the face(s) using [Haar-cascade](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_objdetect/py_face_detection/py_face_detection.html#haar-cascade-detection-in-opencv), which will provide you the rectangle coordinates of the face location. Then you can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52367698/3051961) to blur the desired portion of an image.

Comment: But i cant find there information about detecting random parts of face (hair, forehead and etc.)

Comment: That's a different problem altogether. But  surely you can estimate these features from the bounding rect.