# IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type when using np.where()

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

When I was trying to blend two images with a mask, I used np.where():

*a, b* and *mask* are lists of ndarrays and dtype is float64. *tempImg* is a ndarray with same dtype.

````
```
a = [[179.52181224 196.11236657 199.25513578 200.81821174 198.7369237
  188.63429662 192.30241342 207.88677914 222.15657045 229.51498031
  231.98006343 231.87414046 230.46600773 218.49685369 162.22483198
  100.36016141 121.1080895  135.74811817 130.99244378 110.68895168
  118.30273168 126.86982489 129.77672984 124.48464581 113.252353  ]
 [196.82448164 214.76750918 217.8666702  220.43924199 218.29167364
  206.96139307 210.62221148 226.93273178 242.81860388 250.77400119
  252.75942764 252.58055613 251.7060296  244.7889392  205.30175274
  140.06253874 130.66796303 134.60075016 144.20452322 134.04340699
  134.67761061 134.7536771  134.06737521 132.02019221 125.54434286]
 [199.35308577 217.40897714 220.85336669 223.59548903 221.36787333
  210.40169753 213.24258599 228.92592981 244.90159636 252.59280128
  252.9813501  248.71485061 237.89496352 225.45499552 211.15977205
  167.02392375 125.05120764 110.35189406 137.84965955 135.69712767
  133.58192482 132.36280398 132.31858306 134.45862906 132.1907518 ]]

//b is quite similar to a, same size but different value.
//mask is also the same size but has float values between 0 and 1:
[[0, 0, 0...1, 1, 0.56, 0.94, 1]...]
```
    for i in range (0, len(a)):
        tempImg = tempImg[np.where(mask[i] == 1, a[i], b[i])]
        tempImg = tempImg[np.where(mask[i] > 0 and mask[i] < 1,
                          a[i] * mask[i] + b[i] * (1 - mask[i]), tempImg)]
        img.append(tempImg)
````

Expected results are a new ndarray list (img), but I got following error:

```
in blend
    tempImg = tempImg(np.where(mask[i] == 1, a[i], b[i]))
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

Can anyone help me figure out the problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do `tempImg`, `mask`, `a`, and `b` look like? And what are their dtypes? The error tells you what the problem is, but we can't see it to help

Comment: a, b and mask are lists of ndarrays and the dtype are float64

Comment: Then that violates the necessary `must be of integer (or boolean) type` as referenced in your error message. Essentially, numpy sees that you are trying to index into an array with an index of `[1.0]` or `[2.1]` or something (again, we can't see your data) but indices need to be `[1]` or `[0,2,4]` or `[True, False, True, True]` in order to be valid

Comment: I am not sure which is the index? I thought the index is `i` , just need to give values of `a` or `b` to `tempImg` ?

Comment: If you edit your question with some actual or example data for mask, a, and b, it would very much help us to see what is happening. Right now, this question doesn't meet the criteria for a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks a lot I added the data sample here.

Comment: Thanks for updating, it was very helpful. Basically, when you were attempting to assign using `np.where`, you mixed looping operations with indexing operations in a problematic way. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using lists of arrays, which I assume are representing the rows of your image, use a 2D array as that's how images are usually interpreted. If your image is already defined as a list of arrays you can just do the following to make it a 2D array:

```
import numpy as np
list_of_arrays = [np.asarray([0.1, 0.2]), np.asarray([0.1, 0.2])]
my_image = np.asarray(list_of_arrays)
```

If your mask is already defined you could use OpenCV's `bitwise_and`:
Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.8/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-and) for details on use but
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38493075/6509168) looks like it might very useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for updating your question. Based on your sample data, here is my setup:

```
a = np.array([[179.52181224, 196.11236657, 199.25513578, 200.81821174, 198.7369237,
  188.63429662, 192.30241342, 207.88677914, 222.15657045, 229.51498031,
  231.98006343, 231.87414046, 230.46600773, 218.49685369, 162.22483198,
  100.36016141, 121.1080895 , 135.74811817, 130.99244378, 110.68895168,
  118.30273168, 126.86982489, 129.77672984, 124.48464581, 113.252353  ],
 [196.82448164, 214.76750918, 217.8666702 , 220.43924199, 218.29167364,
  206.96139307, 210.62221148, 226.93273178, 242.81860388, 250.77400119,
  252.75942764, 252.58055613, 251.7060296 , 244.7889392 , 205.30175274,
  140.06253874, 130.66796303, 134.60075016, 144.20452322, 134.04340699,
  134.67761061, 134.7536771 , 134.06737521, 132.02019221, 125.54434286],
 [199.35308577, 217.40897714, 220.85336669, 223.59548903, 221.36787333,
  210.40169753, 213.24258599, 228.92592981, 244.90159636, 252.59280128,
  252.9813501 , 248.71485061, 237.89496352, 225.45499552, 211.15977205,
  167.02392375, 125.05120764, 110.35189406, 137.84965955, 135.69712767,
  133.58192482, 132.36280398, 132.31858306, 134.45862906, 132.1907518]])

b =a**2
mask=np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.56, 0.94, 1,0.7,1,0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.56, 0.94, 1,0.7,1,0, 0, 1, 1, 0.56],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.56, 0.94, 1,0.7,1,0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.56, 0.94, 1,0.7,1,0, 0, 1, 1, 0.56],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.56, 0.94, 1,0.7,1,0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.56, 0.94, 1,0.7,1,0, 0, 1, 1, 0.56]])
tempImg=np.zeros_like(a)
```

The problem you were having was two-fold. First, you were trying to index into `tempImg` with float indices from your other arrays (`tempImg=tempImg[]`).

Solution for this:

```
for i in range (0, len(a)):
    tempImg[i] = np.where(mask[i] == 1, a[i], b[i])
```

Second, and *most important*, you were looping through when you didn't need to do so at all!

Vectorized solution leveraging numpy:

```
tempImg = np.where(mask == 1, a, b)
```