# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, opencv, error-handling

[image: screenshot]I'm trying to run [this project](https://bitbucket.org/BrianTremaine/coin_detect_opencv/src/master/) on my Mac.

There are two main python files in this project I have to run and that's `calibrate.py`, to open the camera and get the images, and `detectCoins.py`, but I'm getting this error every time when I try to build `detectCoins.py`:

```
File "detectCoins.py", line 226, in <module>
    scale = finalHeight / im.shape[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Can anyone tell me how to run this project properly?
Thanks.
  the code

```
import numpy as np
import logging, sys
import yaml

## =========================================================================
# select video & camera and whether to use calibration
VIDEO = 0
camera = 1
CAL = True
# Beaware that camera calibration can move some objects out of the frame
# and as a result contours will be incomplete and return a very small area
#
## ==========================================================================

#qIDref = 2.00*25.4
# ID-1 85.60 x 53.98mm
IDrefW = 53.98
IDrefL = 85.60

def adjust_gamma(image, gamma=1.0):
  # build a lookup table mapping the pixel values [0, 255] to
  # their adjusted gamma values
  invGamma = 1.0 / gamma
  table = np.array([((i / 255.0) ** invGamma) * 255
      for i in np.arange(0, 256)]).astype("uint8")

  # apply gamma correction using the lookup table
  return cv2.LUT(image, table)

def getBoxDim(box1):
  # return length and width of rotated rect
  L = box1[1][1]
  W = box1[1][0]

  return max(L,W), min(L,W)

def checkCoinDia(rc, Wp, Lp, cent):
  # check if radius is a valid coin
  ## absolute size using L and W, dia (mm)
  ##
  ## dime:        17.91
  ## penny:       19.05
  ## nickel:      21.21
  ## quarter:     24.26
  ## fifty-cent:  30.61
  ## ID-1:        (85.6 x 53.98)
  ## business crd ( 3.5*25.4 x 2.0*25.4 )
  dia = rc * 2.0 * (IDrefW) / Wp

  # check coin dia in mm and color flag, penny == True
  result = -1.0
  if dia< 16.2:
      result = -1.0
  elif dia < 18.48:
      if penny == True:
         result = 1.0
      else:
          result = 10.0
  elif dia < 20.13:
      if penny == True:
         result = 1.0
      else:
         result = 10.0
  elif dia < 22.8:
      if penny == True:
          result = 1.0
      else:
          result = 5.0
  elif dia < 27.43:
      result = 25.0
  elif dia < 32.0:
      result = 50.0

  return result, dia

def checkCenter(img, cir, thresh = [30,15]):
  # Check if center (x,y) is greater than bkgd threshold
  cir1 = cir.copy()
  radius = np.int32(6)
  # overwrite radius
  cir1[2] = radius
  metric, _ = getCircleColor(img, cir1, 'hsv')

  #yg = (thresh[1]/(thresh[0]+1)) * metric[0] + 10
  #val = metric[0]

  if metric[0] < 0.4*thresh[0]:
      return True, metric
  else:
      return False, metric


def getCircleColor(image, circ, flag = 'hsv'):
  # return mean of colors over circle from RGB input image
  if flag == 'hsv':
      color = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
  elif flag == 'lab':
      color = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB) 
  else:
      color = image
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469235/opencv-apply-mask-to-a-color-image
  circ = np.uint16(np.around(circ))
  mask = np.full((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]), 0, dtype=np.uint8)   
  cv2.circle(mask, (circ[0], circ[1]), circ[2], (255, 255, 255), -1)

  metric = cv2.mean(color, mask)

  return metric, mask


def getDimePennyDecision(img, circ):
  # use hsv s-v space to discern dime from pennies
  metric, _ = getCircleColor(img, circ, flag = 'hsv')
  h = metric[0]
  s = metric[1]

  penny = True
  #if (1.10 * h -s + 38 > 0):
  if (6.4 * h - s - 75 > 0):
      penny = False

  return penny

def  findRangeAllContours(contours):
   # find x-y range of ALL objects & ID card
   xmin = 9999
   ymin = 9999
   xmax = 0
   ymax = 0

   for c in contours:       
       extLeft = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
       extRight = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
       extTop = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
       extBot = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])

       if extLeft[0] < xmin:
           xmin = extLeft[0]
       if extRight[0] > xmax:
           xmax = extRight[0]
       if extTop[1] < ymin:
           ymin = extTop[1]
       if extBot[1] > ymax:
           ymax = extBot[1]

   rect = [(xmin,ymin), (xmax,ymax)]

   return rect

def  getBkgdMetric(contour, flag = 'hsv'):
   # find color of background
   #
   rectRange = findRangeAllContours(contour)
   x1 = int(rectRange[0][0]/2)
   y1 = int(rectRange[0][1]/2)
   r = int(0.5 * np.sqrt(x1**2 + y1**2))
   circ = [x1, y1, min(r, 15)]
   metric_bkgd, mask_bkgd =  getCircleColor(blurred, circ, 'hsv')

   return metric_bkgd, rectRange

""" ============ main ======================================
"""
if __name__ == '__main__':

logging.basicConfig(filename='coins.log',filemode='w',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.info("Program started")    

if VIDEO:
   cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera)
   logging.info("video capture")
   if (cap.isOpened()== False):
      logging.info("Error opening video stream or file")
else:
   im = cv2.imread('..\images/ID_card1.jpg')
   im = cv2.imread('..\images/ID_card2.jpg')
   im = cv2.imread('..\images/Lucky_ID.jpg')
   im = cv2.imread('..\images/ID_card1.jpg')
   im = cv2.imread('..\images/new_blk.jpg')
   #im = cv2.imread('..\images/compare_blk.jpg')
   im = cv2.imread('..\images/test_final2.jpg')
   #im = cv2.imread('..\images/non-touch.jpg')
   #im = cv2.imread('..\images\ID-1.jpg')
   #im = cv2.imread('..\images/velvBkgd.jpg')
   logging.info("still image")


while(True):
# read image
# ========================================================

   if VIDEO:
      success, im = cap.read()
      if not success:
         logging.info('Failed to read video')
         sys.exit(1)

   # We will run Object detection at an fixed height image
   finalHeight = 640
   # resize image to height finalHeight
   scale = finalHeight / im.shape[0]
   image = cv2.resize(im, None, fx=scale, fy=scale)
   cv2.imshow("Original",image)


   """ Apply camera calibration here, using stored matrices
   # ======================================================
   # file used is calibrate.py
   # matrices stored are:
   """

   if CAL:
     with open('calibration.yaml') as f:
        loadeddict = yaml.load(f)
        K = loadeddict.get('camera_matrix')
        K = np.array(K)
        d = loadeddict.get('dist_coeff')    
        d = np.array(d) 

     # Read an example image and acquire its size
     h, w = image.shape[:2]
     # Generate new camera matrix from parameters
     newcameramatrix, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(K, d, (w,h), 0)
     # Generate look-up tables for remapping the camera image
     mapx, mapy = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(K, d, None, newcameramatrix, (w, h), 5)
     # Remap the original image to a new image
     newimg = cv2.remap(image, mapx, mapy, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

     # Display old and new image
     if(0):
        cv2.imshow("Before map", image)
        cv2.imshow("After map", newimg)

     imageCorr = newimg

   else:
     imageCorr = image

   """ alter gamma
   """
   gamma = adjust_gamma(imageCorr, 2.2)

   """ processing pipeline:
   # ==========================================================
   #   calibrate camera & distortion
   #   gamma
   #   blur before gray
   #   gray blurred image
   #   edge gray image
   #
   """     
   output = gamma.copy()

   # process image
   blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gamma, (3,3), 0)
   cv2.imshow("Blurred", blurred) 

   gray = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   cv2.imshow("gray", gray)

   edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 200, 10) # 50,200
   cv2.imshow("Canny", edged)

   """ find bounding boxes for coins and ID-1
   # ===========================================================
   # find all contours:
   # Pick out largest area as the ID-1 reference
   # use cv2.minAreaRect(cnt) on largest bounding box
   # standard ID-1 as reference (bank card or ID card)
   #
   # Note: contours NOT good for detecting touching coins
   # need segmentation for that.
   """
   (_,contours,_) = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

   ## debug --- draw contours
   #item1 = 0
   #for circ in contours:
      #cv2.drawContours(output, circ, -1, (0,0,255), 3)
      #item1 = item1+1
      #cv2.imshow('contours',output)
      #cv2.waitKey(2000)


   """ get background color
   """
   metric_bkgd, error = getBkgdMetric(contours, 'hsv')

   #print((metric_bkgd))

   if error[0][0]==0 or error[1][0]==image.shape[1]:
       print("ERROR: clipping image in x")
   if error[0][1]==0 or error[1][1]==image.shape[1]:
       print("ERROR clipping image in y")

   cmax = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
   rectID = cv2.minAreaRect(cmax)  # find rotated rectangle

   pnts = cv2.boxPoints(rectID)
   box = np.int0(pnts)
   cv2.drawContours(output,[box],0,(255,0,0),2)
   logging.info("box ID1")
   logging.info(box)
   logging.info("")

   """ find coins and draw circle & bounding rectange using HughCircles
   # ==================================================================
   """
   HIGH = 175 # param1
   LOW = 45   # param2
   circles1 = 25  # set max upper limit for coins
   circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, 20, circles1, \
        param1=HIGH, param2=LOW, minRadius=15,maxRadius=40) #12,45

   # ensure circles exist
   if circles is not None:
     # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
     circlesInt = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

   """ loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the Hough circles and
       use float for precision 
   """
   logging.info("ref")
   L , W = getBoxDim(rectID)
   logging.info([L, W])
   logging.info("circles:")

   coins = 0
   item = 0
   amount = 0.0
   for circ in circlesInt:
      #logging.info([item, circles[item]])
      x = circles[0][item][0]
      y = circles[0][item][1]
      r = circles[0][item][2]

      # check range of x and y within imageCorr
      # --- do it here

      penny = getDimePennyDecision(blurred, circ)
      center, val2 = checkCenter(blurred, circ, thresh = metric_bkgd)

      #print([center, np.around(val2), np.around(metric_bkgd)])
      print(val2)

      value, dia = checkCoinDia(r, W, L, penny)        
      metric, mask_c =  getCircleColor(blurred, circ, 'hsv')


      logging.info([item, int(10*dia)/10, value, np.around(metric), penny, center, val2])      
      #print([item, int(10*dia)/10, value, np.around(metric), penny, center, np.around(val2)]) 

      if value < 0 or not center:
          color = (0,0,255)
          #cv2.putText(output, "{}".format('X'), (int(x), int(y)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, color, 1)
      else:
         coins = coins + 1
         amount = amount + value
         color = (0,255,0)
      # draw the circle in the output image, then print the circle #
      # corresponding to the center of the circle
      cv2.circle(output, (int(x), int(y)), int(r), color, 2)
      cv2.putText(output, "{}".format(int(10*dia)/10), (int(x) - 10, int(y)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, (0, 0, 255), 1)    
      # cv2.putText(output, "{}".format(int(metric[ch])), (int(x) - 10, int(y)+15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, (255, 0, 0), 1) 
      cv2.putText(output, "{}".format(value), (int(x) - 10, int(y)+15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, (255, 0, 0), 1)
      item = item + 1

   logging.info("---")

   cv2.putText(output, "coin count: {}".format(coins), (30, 610), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (255, 255, 255), 2)
   cv2.putText(output, "$: {}".format(amount/100.0), (30, 630), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (255, 255, 255), 2)

   cv2.imshow("output", output)  

   # analyze each coin for color ? if needed ...
   # ==========================================================



   # clean up and exit on waitKey
   # ==========================================================
   Wait = True
   if VIDEO==1 & (cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q')):
     logging.info("exit waitKey")
     Wait = False

   if VIDEO == 0:
      while True:
          if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
              logging.info("exit 'q' key")
              cv2.destroyAllWindows()
              Wait = False
              break
   else:
      cv2.waitKey(200)  # frame rate

   if not Wait:
       break

# save image to disc (use for project report)
file_path = ".\Results/"
cv2.imwrite(file_path + "original" + ".png", image) 
cv2.imwrite(file_path + "calibrated" + ".png", imageCorr) 
cv2.imwrite(file_path + "gamma" + ".png", gamma)
cv2.imwrite(file_path + "gray" + ".png", gray)
cv2.imwrite(file_path + "blur" + ".png", blurred)
cv2.imwrite(file_path + "edged" + ".png", edged)
cv2.imwrite(file_path + "results" + ".png", output)      

if VIDEO:
   cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Could you please provide snippets of the code being run where the error is thrown?

Comment: Please give your code, preferably all of it since the error could be traced through multiple functions.

Comment: @th0nk- i did you have the link in the post

Comment: @BobRobert Here it is https://bitbucket.org/BrianTremaine/coin_detect_opencv/src/master/detectCoins.py

Comment: @th0nk- Ok, sorry I'm new here just a second

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cv2.imread()` and a couple of other operations in `cv2` silently return `None` when it fails. This is not a very nice behavior to have for a function obviouly, as you would expect `cv2` to throw some exception.

The problem is that the code is not checking for those cases. So depending on the source of the `im` variable in your code (probably `cv2.imread('..\images/test_final2.jpg')` at line 206), the `im` variable is being assigned `None` because the reading failed for some reason (file not found, invalid file format, etc).

To solve this problem, just ensure that the returned value is different from `None` when you call a `cv2` function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    logging.basicConfig(filename='coins.log',filemode='w',level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.info("Program started")    

    if VIDEO:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera)
        if (cap.isOpened()== False):
            logging.info("Error while opening camera.")
            sys.exit(0)
        _, image = cap.read()
        logging.info("video capture mode")

    else:
        image = cv2.imread("./image.png")
        if image == None:
            if not os.path.exists("./image.png"):
                logging.info("Still image not found.")
            else:
                logging.info("Error while opening still image.")
            sys.exit(0)
        logging.info("still image mode")
    
    final_height = 640
    scale = final_height / image.shape[0]

    if VIDEO:

        while(True):
            success, image = cap.read()
            if not success:
                logging.info('Failed to read video')
                sys.exit(0)
            image = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=scale, fy=scale)
            cv2.imshow("Original", image)

    else: # still image

        image = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=scale, fy=scale)
        cv2.imshow("Original", image)
```

Comment: Thanks, do You have any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Comment: Just ensure that the return value is different than `None`. Make sure that the local file exists and is in the right format for `cv2` to work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, when I put your code I get a syntax error after else File "detectCoins.py", line 207
    else
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: A semicolon is missing at `else:`. But this is not supposed to be a copy & paste solution, it's just to give you an hint about how to make this work ;)

Comment: yes i solved that problem for else but i'm still getting another error
=> python detectCoins.py
  File "detectCoins.py", line 231
    """ Apply camera calibration here, using stored matrices
                                                           ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
You have mail in /var/mail/huseinhasan1
I know that it's not a copy paste solution, but I'm a beginner with python that's why I'm asking You for assist:)

Comment: That's a line outside the code I provided you. Make sure that the code is correctly aligned. Python requires you to indent nested code using 4 spaces (a tab). Refer to [this](https://www.w3schools.in/python-tutorial/concept-of-indentation-in-python/)