# Why I could not use cv2.split result as masking for my cv2.bitwise_and?

Tags: python, opencv, bitwise-operators, mask

I wonder why this is not work? I tried to do simple operation by splitting OpenCV logo to R,G,and B then I tried to apply the red mask to original image using bitwise and, but why I did not get only red part of the image? What I did wrong? Thank you.

Code Here:

[image]

Comment: You write `bitwise_and`, but your (image of your) code shows `bitwise_or`!?

Comment: I am sorry, I tried both of them but the result still the same.

Comment: @IvanSuryaHutomo Can you please add a link to your original OpenCV logo image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely that your original sample is not "clean enough".
The values of `R` channel that looks black are close to zero but **not** zero.

When using `cv2.bitwise_and` or `cv2.bitwise_or` with a `mask`, all the values in the mask that are not equal to zero are taken as "True" (when mask != 0, the value is like 255).

---

A close inspection of the image you have posted unravels that the value of the black pixels is actually `1` and not `0`:

[image]

---

I downloaded a "clean" OpenCV logo from [here](https://images.app.goo.gl/d9DsrvxTBaNfLrpe6), and it's working as expected:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('OpenCV_Logo.png')

B, G, R = cv2.split(image)

# Using bitwise_or and bitwise_and gives the same result.
masked = cv2.bitwise_or(image, image, mask=R)  

cv2.imshow('Red', R)
cv2.imshow('masked', masked)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

OpenCV_Logo:
[image]

`R`:
[image]

`masked`:
[image]
As you can see there are leftovers around the edges, because the edges are not "pure" zeros.

---

Reproducing your problem is simple:
We may add `1` to all elements of `image`.
For avoiding overflow I used `cv2.add` instead of `+1`: `image = cv2.add(image, np.ones_like(image)`.

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('OpenCV_Logo.png')

image = cv2.add(image, np.ones_like(image))

B, G, R = cv2.split(image)

masked = cv2.bitwise_or(image, image, mask=R)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('Red', R)
cv2.imshow('masked', masked)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:

`image`:
[image]

`R`:
[image]

`masked`:
[image]

As you can see `image` and `R` looks the same, but `masked` result is completely different.

---

Suggested solutions:

1. You may find a better input image.
2. You may apply [cv2.threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57) to `R` for setting all the low values to zero.

`cv2.threshold` applies a threshold, the result is a binary image - all values are either zero or 255.

Example for using `cv2.threshold`:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('OpenCV_Logo.png')

image = cv2.add(image, np.ones_like(image))  # Modify the image for the example.

B, G, R = cv2.split(image)

# cv2.THRESH_OTSU finds the threshold automatically, you may use manual threshold instead.
R = cv2.threshold(R, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

masked = cv2.bitwise_or(image, image, mask=R)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('Red', R)
cv2.imshow('masked', masked)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:

`masked`:
[image]

Comment: Wow thank you. It is really great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do requires the [`cv2.bitwise_and()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga60b4d04b251ba5eb1392c34425497e14) method, not the [`cv2.bitwise_or()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab85523db362a4e26ff0c703793a719b4) method.

Try:

```
masked = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=R)
cv2.imshow('mask', masked)
```

See: [OpenCV - Apply mask to a color image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10469235/13552470) for reference.

Comment: I already tried bitwise_and but the result still the same. I am not sure why.