# how to make all colour under a certain threshold transparent

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm currently overlaying a thermal camera on a normal rgb camera, the thermal camera outputs an image in grey scale.

I'm converting to rgb using a colormap to add colour to the image, then overlaying it to the normal rgb camera. This is working fine

```
thermal = cv2.applyColorMap(thermal, cv2.COLORMAP_HOT)
alpha =0.5
blended_portion = cv.addWeighted(foreground, alpha, background[:foreground_height,:foreground_width,:], 1 - alpha, 0, background)
background[:foreground_height,:foreground_width,:] = blended_portion
cv.imshow('composited image', background)
```

However this code applies that 0.5 opacity to the entire image, is there any way possible where i only decrease the opacity at a certain threshold?
so for example if its cold then its just 0 opacity but when its hot the opacity is 100?

so kind of like this:
[image]

Comment: Does `background[thermal > 50] = blended_portion` work? There is some trick in numpy that lets you set certain pixels. Refer to `numpy.where()` also

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not providing code, but with these resources you should be able to figure it out:

1. See the [thresholding tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) to create a binarized version of your thermal image.
2. Then apply this binary image as a mask to your thermal image so that only the 'hot parts' remain (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10469945/4649452))
3. Now, in your call to `cv.addWeighted()` use the masked thermal image.

Comment: can i get a bit more details on this? im not sure how to implement this method because im already overlaying the images and as i mentioned when i overlay the images and use the threshold it effects the entire photo. i want only the hotspots in the image i want everything else to be transparent

Comment: Can you add picture of what you have right now, and an example picture of what you want? I don't really know how you define "hot" spot. Red is hot I assume, but what about yellow and all these shades of orange