# How to crop image using masked image and overlay on top of other image with same color?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to crop an image based on the mask image and paste the cropped image on the new background image. I was able to achieve this but the cropped image is in gray color instead of color  as in the original image

[image: original source image]

[image: masked image]

[image: Resultant cropped cat image on new background image]

As it can be seen in the above image cropped image color is not the same as the original source cat image color, cropped image is a greyish color whereas in the original image it contains yellow golden color.

my code is as below to perform this

```py
import cv2
src1=cv2.imread('cat.jpg',0)
mask=cv2.imread('mask_cat.jpg',0)
ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(mask, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
src1 [thresh1==0] = 0
h, w = src1.shape
red = (0, 0, 0)
width, height = 1742, 815
back =cv2.cvtColor( create_blank(width, height, rgb_color=red),cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
hh, ww = back.shape
yoff = round((hh-h)/2)
xoff = round((ww-w)/2)
result = back.copy()
result[yoff:yoff+h, xoff:xoff+w] = src1
```

How can I get the same color in the cropped image as the original source color from where it cropped? Any suggestion or help solving this will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV - Apply mask to a color image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469235/opencv-apply-mask-to-a-color-image)

Comment: @Bilal Noo, I tried  that approach but still I'm getting grey image

Comment: "*I tried that approach ...*", can you please tell me in terms of code how did you applied this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import cv2
cat = cv2.imread('cat.jpg')
mask_cat = cv2.imread('mask_cat.jpg', 0)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(cat,cat,mask = mask_cat)
```

[image]

I also see you try to reshape the image.It can be done as follows.

```
width, height = 1742, 815
reshaped_result = cv2.resize(result, dsize=(width, height))
```

[image]

To place the cropped image on resized image

```
width, height = 1742, 815
result_final = np.zeros((height,width,3), np.uint8)
h, w = result.shape[:2]
hh, ww = result_final.shape[:2]
yoff = round((hh-h)/2)
xoff = round((ww-w)/2)
result_final[yoff:yoff+h, xoff:xoff+w] = result
```

[image]

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, this works , is it possible to paste cropped image on resized image ? so cropped image won't get zoomed

Comment: there you go. I have edited it as you want